# how to read public timeline feed in facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.3

I need to read timeline feed in facebook public pages. I have used syntax to get the feed from timeline:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/DoveIndia?fields=id,name,picture,feed
```

It works well and returns the feed,when facebook page not have "Posts To Page".
When Page have "Posts To Page",it only returns all posted messages on page not timeline feeds.

Example of a request(Graph API Explorer tools):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/jeep?fields=id,name,picture,feed
```

Please suggest how can read feed from timelines?

Thanks
Sameek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /{page-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this page.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

Comment: Hi.  Got any example you can post on JSFiddle?  I'm having a hard time making it work and I already spent half-a-day.  =(

Comment: there is example code for many languages in the api reference, and you can test api calls in the api explorer

Answer (score 0):

The feed of posts (including status updates) and links published by this person, or by others on this person's profile. There are other edges which provide filtered versions of this edge:

```
/{user-id}/posts shows only the posts that were published by this person.
/{user-id}/tagged shows only the posts that this person was tagged in.
```

All of these derivative edges share the exact same reading structure, however /feed should be used for all publishing purposes.